# Subsetting one dataframe from another does not give expected result

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` contains 2 columns - `t1` and `data1`, with `t1` starting from 0.0001 till 75, with an increment of 0.0001. So it goes like 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003..... 74.9999, 75.0000. data1 is just some numbers between 0 and 1.

`df2` also contains 2 columns - `t2` and `data2`, but the length of each column is 114 - only selected values between 0.0001 and 75 are present in the time column - eg. 14.6000,15.2451,....73.4568. data2 is again some random numbers with length of 114
I have extracted the values of t2 from another data set

```
t2<- c(14.6000, 14.6001, 14.6002, 14.6002, 14.6007, 14.6011, 14.6016, 14.602, 14.6037, 14.6055, 14.6072, 14.6089, 14.6151, 14.6214, 14.6277, 14.6339, 14.6402, 14.6545, 14.6688, 14.6831, 14.6974, 14.7117, 14.7261, 14.7573, 14.7886, 14.8199, 14.8511, 14.8824, 14.9137, 14.9681, 15.0225, 15.0768, 15.1312, 15.1856, 15.24, 15.3233, 15.4065, 15.4897, 15.573, 15.6562, 15.7394, 15.8768, 16.0142, 16.1516, 16.289, 16.4264, 16.5638, 16.7676, 16.9715, 17.1753, 17.3792, 17.583, 17.7868, 17.9907, 18.3366, 18.6826, 19.0285, 19.3745, 19.7204, 20.0664, 20.4124, 20.9122, 21.412, 21.9118, 22.4116, 22.9114, 23.4112, 23.911, 24.5965, 25.282, 25.9675, 26.653, 27.3385, 28.024, 29.1158, 30.2075, 31.2993, 32.3911, 33.4828, 34.6828, 35.8828, 37.0828, 38.2828, 39.4828, 40.6828, 41.8828, 43.0828, 44.2828, 45.4828, 46.6828, 47.8828, 49.0828, 50.2828, 51.4828, 52.6828, 53.8828, 55.0828, 56.2828, 57.4828, 58.6828, 59.8828, 61.0828, 62.2828, 63.4828, 64.6828, 65.8828, 67.0828, 68.2828, 69.4828, 70.6828, 71.8828, 73.0828, 74.2828,74.6000)


df1<- data.frame("t1"=seq(0.0001,75,0.0001), "data1"=c(rnorm(750000)))

df2<- data.frame("t2"=t2, "data2"=c(rnorm(length(t2))))
```

I want to create a new dataframe - `df_new` , in which I want to pick the values of `t2` and the corresponding `data1` values from `df1`

```
df_new<- subset(df1,t1 %in% df2$t2)
```

When I do this, `df_new` has only 74 observations, instead of 114.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Note that you have a duplicate in t2 so you'll get 113 elements, not 114

Comment: Yes, and the solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with floating point arithmetic. See two examples below. In general, directly comparing floats like this is not necessarily going to be robust because the accuracies of the representation isn't perfect. I picked the first element in `df2$t2` that doesn't line up as expected. You would hope that the first `==` comparison would return true but it doesn't. See that `all.equal`, which confusingly tests "near equality", does in fact return true for the two objects I pulled out. You can see that there is a difference by changing the digits printed with `options`.

One way to get the intended result is to use `round` to make all the numbers you want the same. Note that there are only 113 rows in your output because there are only 113 unique values in `df2$t2` as provided. You might also consider converting to integers (with correspondingly smaller units).

```r
t2<- c(14.6000, 14.6001, 14.6002, 14.6002, 14.6007, 14.6011, 14.6016, 14.602, 14.6037, 14.6055, 14.6072, 14.6089, 14.6151, 14.6214, 14.6277, 14.6339, 14.6402, 14.6545, 14.6688, 14.6831, 14.6974, 14.7117, 14.7261, 14.7573, 14.7886, 14.8199, 14.8511, 14.8824, 14.9137, 14.9681, 15.0225, 15.0768, 15.1312, 15.1856, 15.24, 15.3233, 15.4065, 15.4897, 15.573, 15.6562, 15.7394, 15.8768, 16.0142, 16.1516, 16.289, 16.4264, 16.5638, 16.7676, 16.9715, 17.1753, 17.3792, 17.583, 17.7868, 17.9907, 18.3366, 18.6826, 19.0285, 19.3745, 19.7204, 20.0664, 20.4124, 20.9122, 21.412, 21.9118, 22.4116, 22.9114, 23.4112, 23.911, 24.5965, 25.282, 25.9675, 26.653, 27.3385, 28.024, 29.1158, 30.2075, 31.2993, 32.3911, 33.4828, 34.6828, 35.8828, 37.0828, 38.2828, 39.4828, 40.6828, 41.8828, 43.0828, 44.2828, 45.4828, 46.6828, 47.8828, 49.0828, 50.2828, 51.4828, 52.6828, 53.8828, 55.0828, 56.2828, 57.4828, 58.6828, 59.8828, 61.0828, 62.2828, 63.4828, 64.6828, 65.8828, 67.0828, 68.2828, 69.4828, 70.6828, 71.8828, 73.0828, 74.2828,74.6000)

set.seed(12345)
df1<- data.frame("t1"=seq(0.0001,75,0.0001), "data1"=c(rnorm(750000)))

df2<- data.frame("t2"= t2, "data2"=c(rnorm(length(t2))))

df2$t2[2]
#> [1] 14.6001
df1$t1[146001]
#> [1] 14.6001

df1$t1[146001] == df2$t2[2]
#> [1] FALSE
all.equal(df1$t1[146001], df2$t2[2])
#> [1] TRUE

options(digits = 22)
df2$t2[2]
#> [1] 14.600099999999999
df1$t1[146001]
#> [1] 14.600100000000001

df_new_rnd <- subset(df1, round(t1, 4) %in% round(df2$t2, 4))
df_new_int <- subset(df1, as.integer(t1 * 10000) %in% as.integer(df2$t2 * 10000))
nrow(df_new_rnd)
#> [1] 113
nrow(df_new_int)
#> [1] 113
```

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This works: `df_new<- subset(df1,as.integer(10000*t1) %in% as.integer(10000*df2$t2))`